# Create AlertDialog in Android on a class that extends SurfaceView

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog, surfaceview

Hey, 
So I have searched the internet high and low for this.
Whenever, someone makes a dialog they do it on a class extending Activity.
So I have a class extends SurfaceView and I need to show a dialog every time the player in my game destroys a certain number of enemies.

How do I do this?
I keep getting errors on the code I copy from online.

This is my class :-

```
class SurvivorPanel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
```

This is my constructor:-

```
 public SurvivorPanel(Context context) { // set panel's holder & thread
    super(context);
    getHolder().addCallback(this);
    _thread = new TutorialThread(getHolder(), this);
    setFocusable(true);
}
```

Some one please advise me how to create an AlertDialog here....

Answer (score 1):

Just use the context that you received in your constructor.

With regards to your question... you can divide it. You can put everything except the `dialog.show()` in the constructor; then you can execute `dialog.show()` and `dialog.dismiss()` elsewhere:

```
private AlertDialog dialog;

public Constructor(Context context){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    dialog = builder.setTitle("The title")
        .setMessage("The content")
        .create();
    dialog.show();
}

public void someWhere(){
    dialog.show();
    // or when you want to close it:
    dialog.dismiss();
}
```

Comment: Where do I put this? Should I put it in the constructor itself? How do I have it in another method??

Comment: Hey, I tried doing that. 
But, I get a force close error whenever I try to show the dialog...

My LogCAT gives me errors at the line where I have dialog.show();
And it gives an error in my Thread in the method which contains the statement (updatePhysics)

01-26 16:10:31.977: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(387):at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
01-26 16:10:31.977: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(387):at com.neivin.android.game.SurvivorPanel.updatePhysics(SurvivorPanel.java:215)
01-26 16:10:31.977: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(387): at com.neivin.android.game.TutorialThread.run(TutorialThread.java:32)

Comment: You cannot do that from another thread which is not your UI thread. Try to use a Handler or the `runOnUiThread` method (Google a bit about them).